# C# Webbrowser disable only one Scrollbar and set starting position on website

Tags: browser, position, scrollbar

I am using a Webbrowser on my new project and I want the scrollbar at the bottom to start at a specific position. Then I want only the scrollbar at the right to show, so you can't navigate from left to right and right to left.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To scroll vertical you can check
         http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/vertical_scroll.cfm

To scroll at specific position you can use

var xpos= document.getElementById('txtXpos').value;

var ypos= document.getElementById('txtYpos').value;

window.scrollTo(xpos,ypos);

```
<p>X-axis <input type="text" id="txtXpos" /></p>
<p>Y-axis <input type="text" id="txtYpos" /></p>
```

To scroll at element you can use

window.location.href = "#elementid"

Comment: No, no code for the Website, I need code for the webbrowser element which I'm using in my form. I can't change the Website. But thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: Thanks, the scrolling worked, How can i disable the lower scroll bar?